# Move camera on global XZ plane regardless of local angle (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am scripting the movement of the main camera on the XZ axis. The camera should move horizontally (forward, back, right, left) when the cursor approaches one of the corresponding screen edges. 
The right-left movement works perfectecly;

[To the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOY0w.png)

[To the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MMT8.png)

on the other hand, moving the camera back-forward on its z axis does not work since the camera is slightly rotated.

[Camera tilt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIQQ6.png)

Therefore, when you try to move it forward horizontally, it instead gets closer to the objects.

[Closer when it should move forward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jExfx.png)

[Away when it should move back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1xxt.png)

```
      if (Input.mousePosition.y >= Screen.height - brdThcknss)
            { //this line is to be replaced
                //transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * panSpeed);
            }
            if (Input.mousePosition.y <= brdThcknss)
            {//this line is to be replaced
                //transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * panSpeed);
            }
            if (Input.mousePosition.x >= Screen.width - brdThcknss)
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * panSpeed);
            }
            if (Input.mousePosition.x <= brdThcknss)
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * panSpeed);
            }
```

It is also necessary to mention that the camera should move througout the XZ plane of the world regardless of the angle of the camera (the camera orbits). What could I replace the commented lines for so that the camera performs the desired movement?

Comment: Please take a look at the overloaded method for transform.translate, in the unity documentation.

Answer (score 0):

AresCaelum's comment is likely correct, but if you'd like to avoid the Translate function altogether, you could simply assign a new Vector3 to the object's position.

Something like:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(newX, transform.position.y, newZ);
```

it could also be done on the localPosition like

```
transform.localposition = new Vector3(x,y,z);
```

If you want to avoid creating a new Vector3 every time you're running this code, you could simply have a Vector3 variable (let's call it 'pos') and do

```
Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;

void Start()
{
   pos.y = whateverYValueYouWant;
}

void Update()
{
    pos.x = newX;
    pos.z = newZ;
    transform.position = pos;
}
```

Comment: My comment is correct =) transform.Translate has a default parameter for a Space variable, by default this is Space.Self, however if you change that to Space.World the movement is done in world space.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html